# Optimized Bubble Sort time for sorting int arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, bubble-sort

I'm currently working on an essay, in which I compare sorting times of certain algorithms. I've written an optimized version of bubble sort, which checks if there is a swap, if not, it stops.

```
void bubble_sort(int* tab, int n) {
    int zamiana, x, i;
    do {
        zamiana = 0;
        for (int counter = 0, i = 1; i < n; ++counter, ++i) {
            if (tab[counter] > tab[i]) {
                x = tab[counter];
                tab[counter] = tab[i];
                tab[i] = x;
                zamiana = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (zamiana != 0);
}
```

I have found that it takes almost 0s to sort array sorted in ascending order, now I'm testing it on an array sorted in descending order, and times are almost the same as for ascending order. **Is it normal?**

Code tested:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void quickSort(int* tab, int lewy, int prawy) {
    int x, y = lewy - 1, z = prawy + 1, pivot = tab[(lewy + prawy) / 2];
    while (1) {
        while (pivot < tab[++y]);
        while (pivot > tab[--z]);
        if (y <= z) {
            x = tab[y];
            tab[y] = tab[z];
            tab[z] = x;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (z > lewy) {
        quickSort(tab, lewy, z);
    }
    if (y < prawy) {
        quickSort(tab, y, prawy);
    }
}

void bubble_sort(int* tab, int n) {
    int zamiana, x, i;
    do {
        zamiana = 0;
        for (int counter = 0, i = 1; i < n; ++counter, ++i) {
            if (tab[counter] > tab[i]) {
                x = tab[counter];
                tab[counter] = tab[i];
                tab[i] = x;
                zamiana = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (zamiana != 0);
}

int main (){
    int* tab;
    int n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    scanf("%d", &n);            //user input array size 
    tab = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for (int counter = 0; counter < n; ++counter) {
        tab[counter] = (rand() % 200) - 100;        //<-100;100>
    }
    quickSort(tab, 0, n);                   //sorting array to get descending order
    clock_t start = clock();
    bubble_sort(tab, n);                                            //sorting array 
    clock_t end = clock();
    float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time elapsed: %f", seconds);
}
```

Comment: No, it's not normal. If the input array is already sorted in ascending order, the "optimized" algorithm only needs to look at every element once and then finishes. This is what you observe. If the input array is sorted in descending order, you need O(n^2) swaps to properly sort it. This should be significantly slower. Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your benchmark, preferably on godbolt.org or similar so we can easily reproduce your results?

Comment: You should check different source data, random, nearly sorted, reverse, few unique, every other increasing/decreasing etc.

Comment: And what value of `n` did you enter?

Comment: I've added something that can be tested

Comment: I enter values from 10000 to 700000

Comment: And what time did you measure for 700000?

Comment: 0,06 seconds for 700000

Comment: An "Optimized Bubble Sort" is an oxymoron -- similar to "Military Intelligence". The words just don't go together. Rather than reinventing the wheel, C provides `qsort()` which is hard to beat from an optimization standpoint.

Comment: You potentially invoke undefined behaviour on the line `tab[counter] = (rand() % 200) - 100` when `counter = n`. You should change the `for`-loop stopping clause to `counter < n` to avoid this. Also, your `malloc` call is incorrect. You should instead have done `malloc(n * sizeof(int))`. Generally, you want to do something like `tab = malloc(n * sizeof (*tab))`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Lol :D What a great, sensible thought you produced C:

Comment: @Mr_t 0,06 seconds for 700000 doesn't seem right. It's too long if the array is ascending, and too short if the array is descending. I suggest that you simplify the code. Remove the random number code, and the qsort code. Just fill the array with a simple incrementing pattern, or decrementing pattern, and then call the bubble sort.

Comment: Your program does not “do” anything—there is no output from the sorts. That means the compiler is allowed to optimize away essentially everything except reading the clock and printing the elapsed time. You should check the generated assembly.

Comment: The way you have the code above you first generate the sample data, then pass it to `quickSort`, then to `bubble_sort` - that means that the data will already be sorted when `bubble_sort` gets it.

Comment: Also, Polish is an epic language, but I'd recommend refraining from non-english identifiers given the fact you're most likely already studying college atm. Among other issues, it lowers the ability of other SO users to interpret your code correctly.

Comment: The code you added does not compare the runtime for inputs that were sorted in ascending and descending order -- it only runs once, for descending input. If I add a second call to the bubble sort function, I can not reproduce your measurement: on descending input, the algorithm took 0.09s, while on ascending input, it took 0.000006s ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/czKKPr15j)). This is what we would expect. Again, if you don't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we will not be able to discuss anything meaningful here.